# Indicate on an Argand Diagram the region of the complex plane in which $ 0 \leq \arg (z+1) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} $

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

> > Question: Indicate on an Argand Diagram the region of the complex plane in which $$ 0 \leq \arg (z+1) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} $$

---

I've tried this

Consider $$ 0 \leq \arg (z+1) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} $$

Split it into two inequalities : $ 0 \leq \arg (z+1)  $ and $\arg (z+1) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} $

Then:

$$ z+1 \Leftrightarrow x+iy+1 \Leftrightarrow (x+1)+i(y) $$

$$ \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\Im(z)}{\Re(z)} \right) = \arg(z+1)$$

$$ \Leftrightarrow  \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x+1} \right) = \arg(z+1)$$

So for the first inequality

$$ 0 \leq \arg (z+1)  $$

$$ 0 \leq \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x+1} \right) $$

$$ 0 \leq \frac{y}{x+1} $$

$$ 0 \leq y ~~ x \neq -1 $$

Second Inequality:

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{x+1} \right) \leq \frac{2\pi}{3} $$

$$ \frac{y}{x+1} \leq -\sqrt{3} $$

$$ y \leq  -\sqrt{3} (x+1) $$

So we have two conditions

$$ 0 \leq y ~~ x \neq -1 $$

and $$ y \leq  -\sqrt{3} (x+1) $$

How do I draw these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You switched the sign of the inequality somewhere. It should be $y\ge-\sqrt3(x+1)$. So you plot the two lines $y=0$ and $y=-\sqrt3(x+1)$ and mark the sector between them as shown.

Comment: Wait why is the inequality sign suppose to be switched is it because -(3)^(1/2) is negative?

Comment: You have correctly identified that we must have $y\ge0$ since $\arg(z)<0$ for $y<0$. The problem comes with deciding what $\arg(z+1)\le\frac{2\pi}{3}$ means. Using $\tan^{-1}\theta$ is tricky, because we take the range of $\tan^{-1}\theta$ to be $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})$. But it is clear from the graph above that we want $z$ to lie to the right of the downward sloping bold line which has endpoint $(-1,0)$ and makes an angle $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ with the positive $x$-axis and hence has equation $y=-\sqrt3(x+1)$.